# React native 'OneSignal/OneSignal.h' file not found

Tags: javascript, xcode, react-native, react-native-onesignal

So as in title I'm getting 'OneSignal/OneSignal.h' file not found error while trying to build my react-native app through xcode, but the thing is that it's happening ONLY for debug build (which is the one running on my emulator), production build works fine
and what's more 'funny' when xcode throws the error it shows it inside the file for few seconds only, after that it 'recognises' that the 'OneSignal/OneSignal.h' file is indeed in my deps and it disapears, however trying to build it for debug always throws it.

It started to happen after I've upgraded my system to Sonoma 14.3 with xcode 15.2, currently on react-native 0.72.10